# How can I determine if all the values in an array are different, in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am using Matlab R2014a and I want to find out if the numbers from an array are different from each other or not. Of course, I can do that in a loop, but I think there are better ways (aka Matlab functions) to do this.

**Example:**

If

```
A=[4 6 8 3] => msgbox ('Elements are different')
```

and if

```
A=[4 4 8 3] => msgbox ('Elements are not different').
```

Is there any function to do this, or I need to do it by brute force?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some alternatives to `unique`.

The result of either of the following is `true` is all elements of `A` are distinct, and `false` otherwise.

- Sort elements and see if some consecutive elements are equal:

  ```
  result = all(diff(sort(A(:)))~=0);
  ```
- Compute distance for all pairs of elements excluding self-pairs, and see if any is zero:

  ```
  result = ~any(pdist(A(:))==0);
  ```
- Compare each pair of elements including self-pairs, and see if the number of coincidences is only the number of self-pairs:

  ```
  result = nnz(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), A(:).'))==numel(A);
  ```
- Use `ismember` (second output) to determine the lowest-index element of `A` that equals each element of `A`:

  ```
  [~, jj] = ismember(A,A);
  result = all(jj==(1:numel(A)));
  ```

Comment: I personally like `pdist` approach +1

Comment: @LuisMendo these are all fun exercises, but they all seem quite a bit more complex than just using `unique`. I haven't done the timings, but I would guess they are typically quite a bit slower as well. Your second bullet even requires purchasing a toolbox.

Comment: @SamRoberts Sure, they are intended as somewhat funny alternatives. I'd go for the `unique` approach. As for timing, however, the `sort`-based approach seems to be a little faster. Try `A = randi(1e3,1,1e5); timeit(@() numel(A) == numel(unique(A))), timeit(@() all(diff(sort(A(:)))~=0))`

Comment: @LuisMendo unfortunately `all(diff(sort(A(:)))~=0))` doesn't always give the right answer - try `A = [Inf,Inf]`.

Comment: @SamRoberts Good point. However, the OP says "I want to find out if the _numbers_ from an array...", so I assume there are no `inf`'s. Besides, the question of whether `inf` equals `inf` is always debatable, from a mathematical point of view

Comment: @all: Unfortunately, unique doesn't serve my purposes, because it also sorts the values and because I don't really need them sorted. All I need is the yes/no binary answer :)

Comment: @SamRoberts They may be fun exercises, but for a beginner in Matlab programming like me, they are very useful too :)

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, there are no inf's. Only numbers.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you very much. I chose the *result = all(diff(sort(A(:)))~=0);* alternative, although all the answers provided here are what I was looking for. Too bad I cannot mark as accepted all the answers provided here :(

Comment: Bogdan, whether or not you require a sorted output, the simplest solutions to this problem are going to carry out a sort operation. The answers provided by me and RobertStettler do this using `unique`, giving you a yes/no answer but without burdening you with an unnecessary sorted output. @LuisMendo, I think you know that `inf==inf` is not really debatable, it's true by an IEEE convention that's accepted by all numerical software.

Comment: @SamRoberts I meant from a mathematical point of view (for example, inf-inf is undefined, so it's not zero). But that may be nitpicking, I admit

Answer (score 4):

I would use

```
if numel(A) == numel(unique(A))
    msgbox ('Elements are different')
else
    msgbox ('Elements are not different')
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this serve your demand?

```
isequal(numel(A), numel(unique(A)))
```